# FIPY axisymmetric 2D with GMSH

Tags: fipy

I'll have to approach a problem involving plasma chemistry in a reactor. It would be useful to describe the problem in 2D axi-symmetric configuration. 
I'd like to use Fipy, but since I solve for electromagnetic fields with GETDP (which uses GMSH mesher), I'd like to know if fipy can handle 2Dgmsh meshes and set it as 2D axi-symmetric domain, before get into it.
I'm not able to find this information in the user manual.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

FiPy's default no-flux boundary conditions represent mirror symmetry at the boundaries. If you want rotational symmetry, that would require adaptation along the lines of the CylindricalGrid2D classes. It wouldn't be hard, but would need some additional code to adjust the face areas and cell volumes. See http://matforge.org/fipy/browser/fipy/fipy/meshes/cylindricalUniformGrid2D.py and related modules.